# Django OperationalError (1142, REFERENCES command denied to user) during migration

Tags: mysql, django, django-migrations

With local MySQL was fine, but with the production is the error. After this error I see only the following tables in the database: `auth_group`, `auth_group_permissions`, `auth_permission`, `django_content_type` and `django_migrations`

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: djoser, messages, rest_framework, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, authtoken, blog, commands, contenttypes, faq, servers, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1142, "REFERENCES command denied to user 'test_user'@'22.161.40.219' for table 'django_content_type'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

After the above error occurs:

1. Run `python manage.py migrate` again, after which you will probably get another error like `"'table_name' already exists"`.
2. Run `python manage.py migrate <app> --fake` command for the application with which the `'table_name'` table is associated.
3. Try these 2 steps until all the necessary tables in the database are created.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I recently came across very much the same issue, and the solution was a stupid thing that I had overlooked.

While the accepted solution does work, it might end up frustrating you if you have a lot of apps and don't know where the error originated from.

This was my permissions set for the user i was using for the mysql connection

```
GRANT SELECT,INSERT,CREATE,ALTER,DROP,LOCK TABLES,CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, DELETE,UPDATE,EXECUTE ON customdb.* TO 'user'@'%';
```

What i had not realized at the time was that `REFERENCES` was a permission to be set.

I ran

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON customdb.* tp 'user'@'%';
```

on my MySQL and Voila, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issues, and although the first answer about running all those python commands until all tables are created, works, it is time consuming and you might have to perform a lot of those commands back and forward until, eventually every table is created.

But python tells us what is the real problem:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1142, "REFERENCES command denied to
> user 'meta'@'localhost' for table 'littlelemon.django_content_type'")

So, the user that is trying to perform the migration doesn't have the permission to use the references command.

Check this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

**The privilege - REFERENCES - enables foreign key creation.**

So in order to fix this, you can run this command within an account with admin privileges:

`GRANT REFERENCES ON your_database_name.* TO 'your_username'@'your_host';`

Or if you are working with workbench, you can go to:

the admin connection < management < Users and Privileges <  choose the account that you are using to perform the migrations < Schema privileges < Add entry < And select the REFERENCES privilege in the DDL Rights.

After that, I advise you to drop every table that you might have from the failed migration, and run the python manage.py migrate again.

This time there will be no errors and all the tables are going to be created successfully.

Hope it helps resolve the issue and to better understand the problem.